# How to get rid of persistent notifications when in full screen?

Tags: firefox, 22.04, gnome-shell, notification, fullscreen

Whenever I get a notification while watching video in full screen (for example in Firefox), it will not go away automatically after a few seconds like one would expect but rather it stays on top of the screen until I close it manually.

How can I make it go away after a few seconds, or hide it when in full screen? I know about the do not disturb switch but I don't want to flick it every time I enter and exit full screen. In my experience, notification systems on all other major platforms stay out of your hair when using applications in full screen.

Comment: Staying on top and full screens are very different situations..

Comment: I've edited the question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, it's clearer but for what you want there's no answer. The reason was already included in my answer below, nothing else to add.

Answer (score 0):

In standard Ubuntu (with GNOME) you can click the Date/Time (top middle menu) and select "Do not disturb" to avoid notifications.

That said, there's nothing to "correct" here because what you describe - persistent notifications, NOT "full screen" - is the intended behavior, i.e., working as designed.